# When is a Radon Nikodym derivative integrable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\nu \ll \mu$ be two measures on the same measure space. Consider the Radon Nikodym derivative
$$\nu(A) = \int_A f d\mu$$
Which requirements must $\nu$ and $\mu$ meet for $f$ to be integrable, i.e.,
$\int |f|d\mu <\infty$, or quasi-integrable, i.e., at least one of the following is true $\int f^+d\mu <\infty$ or $\int f^- d\mu <\infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of the Radon Nikodym derivative $f$
is guaranteed by the Radon Nikodym theorem,
which requires that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.
See e.g. Donald Cohn's *Measure Theory*, page 132.
It may be good to note that the theorem as stated there
for positive $\nu$
also requires $\nu$ to be $\sigma$-finite,
but on page 138 in Exercise 6 it says that this assumption can be dropped
if $f$ is allowed to take values in $[0,\infty]$.

If $\nu$ is a positive measure then $f$ will be nonnegative almost everywhere.
Then (trivially) the integrability of $f$ is equivalent to $\nu$ being finite.

If $\nu$ is a signed measure then the existence of $f$ is guaranteed by
(another version of) the Radon Nikodym theorem,
which requires $\nu$ to be finite.
See e.g. page 135 in Cohn's *Measure Theory*.
This would then imply integrability of $f$.
Here in fact integrability of $f$ is also equivalent to $\nu$ being finite: $f$ is integrable iff $f^+$ and $f^-$ are, i.e., iff the positive and negative parts of $\nu$ are finite, i.e., iff $\nu$ is finite.
I am not sure whether the condition of $\nu$ being finite can be dropped,
to then only have integrability of $f^+$ of $f^-$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So does it only depend on the measure $\nu$ and not on the measure $\mu$?

Comment: I added the equivalence of integrability of $f$ and finiteness of $\nu$ in the case of a signed measure $\nu$.

Comment: @guest1 Yes: the integrability of $f$ is equivalent to the finiteness of $\nu$, both when $\nu$ is positive and when it is a signed measure. The condition on $\mu$ of being $\sigma$-finite is only needed to ensure the existence of $f$ as a Radon Nikodym derivative of $\nu$ w.r.t. $\mu$.